# NumPy: indexing array by list of tuples - how to do it correctly?

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I am in the following situation - I have the following:

- Multidimensional numpy array `a` of `n` dimensions
- `t`, an array of `k` rows (tuples), each with `n` elements. In other words, each row in this array is an index in `a`

What I want: from `a`, return an array `b` with `k` scalar elements, the `i`th element in `b` being the result of indexing `a` with the `i`th tuple from `t`.

Seems trivial enough. The following approach, however, does not work

```py
def get(a, t):
    # wrong result + takes way too long
    return a[t]
```

I have to resort to doing this iteratively i.e. the following works correctly:

```py
def get(a, t):
    res = []
    for ind in t:
        a_scalar = a
        for i in ind:
            a_scalar = a_scalar[i]

        # a_scalar is now a scalar
        res.append(a_scalar)

    return res
```

This works, except for the fact that given that each dimension in `a` has over 30 elements, the procedure does get really slow when `n` gets to more than 5. I understand that it would be slow regardless, however, I would like to exploit numpy's capabilities as I believe it would speed up this process considerably.

Comment: This is a good example for why you should only use code markup for `code` and italics for *variable names*.

Answer (score 1):

The key to getting this right is to understand the roles of indexing lists and tuples.  Often the two are treated the same, but in `numpy` indexing, tuples, list and arrays convey different information.

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                          
In [2]: t = np.array([(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)])                                       

In [4]: a                                                                       
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [5]: t                                                                       
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

You tried:

```
In [6]: a[t]                                                                    
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```

So what's wrong with it?  It ran, but selected a (3,2) array of rows of `a`.  That is, it applied `t` to just the first dimension, effectively `a[t, :]`.  You want to index on all dimensions, some sort of `a[t1, t2]`.  That's the same as `a[(t1,t2)]` - a tuple of indices.

```
In [10]: a[tuple(t[0])]                # a[(0,0)]                                         
Out[10]: 0
In [11]: a[tuple(t[1])]                # a[(1,1)]                                         
Out[11]: 5
In [12]: a[tuple(t[2])]                                                         
Out[12]: 10
```

or doing all at once:

```
In [13]: a[(t[:,0], t[:,1])]                                                      
Out[13]: array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

Another way to write it, is `n` lists (or arrays), one for each dimension:

```
In [14]: a[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]                                                     
Out[14]: array([ 0,  5, 10])

In [18]: tuple(t.T)                                                             
Out[18]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
In [19]: a[tuple(t.T)]                                                          
Out[19]: array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

More generally, in `a[idx1, idx2]` array `idx1` is broadcast against `idx2` to produce a full selection array.  Here the 2 arrays are 1d and match, the selection is your `t` set of pairs.  But the same principle applies to selecting a set of rows and columns, `a[ [[0],[2]], [0,2,3] ]`.

Using the ideas in [10] and following, your `get` could be sped up with:

```
In [20]: def get(a, t): 
    ...:     res = [] 
    ...:     for ind in t: 
    ...:         res.append(a[tuple(ind)])  # index all dimensions at once 
    ...:     return res 
    ...:                                                                        
In [21]: get(a,t)                                                               
Out[21]: [0, 5, 10]
```

If `t` really was a list of tuples (as opposed to an array built from them), your get could be:

```
In [23]: tl = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)]                                               
In [24]: [a[ind] for ind in tl]                                                 
Out[24]: [0, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Explore using np.ravel_multi_index

Create some test data

```
arr = np.arange(10**4)
arr.shape=10,10,10,10
t = []
for j in range(5):
    t.append( tuple(np.random.randint(10, size = 4)))

print(t)
# [(1, 8, 2, 0),
#  (2, 3, 3, 6),
#  (1, 4, 8, 5),
#  (2, 2, 6, 3),
#  (0, 5, 0, 2),]

ta = np.array(t).T
print(ta)
# array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 0],
#        [8, 3, 4, 2, 5],
#        [2, 3, 8, 6, 0],
#        [0, 6, 5, 3, 2]])

arr.ravel()[np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(ta), (10,10,10,10))]
# array([1820, 2336, 1485, 2263,  502]
```

np.ravel_multi_index basically calculates, from the tuple of input arrays, the index into a flattened array that starts with shape (in this case) (10, 10, 10, 10).

Does this do what you need?  Is it fast enough?